# Fatal Error When Sending Freeform

Tags: solspace-freeform, error, core, fatal, act

[image]I am Receiving "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /libraries/Core.php on line 575" on sending FreeForm, i am using ee 2.10.1 and freeform 4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes outlined in [this post](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21481/fatal-error-after-submitting-entry-from-frontend) and it solved my issues.